# Returning all rows and columns

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms

I'm working on a basic mysql database class, with a couple of functions. One of the functions should return a list of all rows and columns. The code is working, and it's pretty dynamic, but it also looks like it could be improved. I was hoping someone could take a look at this code and tell me if there's another solution to doing this?

One of the other solutions I tried was without lists, but it involved recreating an array for every row it had to return, so I dropped that and moved on to lists.

```
    public List<object[]> ReadAllRows(string sQuery)
    {
        List<object[]> oResults = new List<object[]>();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand msCommand = new MySqlCommand
            {
                CommandText = sQuery,
                Connection = Connection
            };

            using (MySqlDataReader msReader = msCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(!msReader.HasRows)
                    return EmptyList;

                while (msReader.Read())
                {
                    object[] oRowValues = new object[msReader.FieldCount];
                    {
                        msReader.GetValues(oRowValues);
                    }

                    oResults.Add(new object[] { oRowValues });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            LastError = "Error: " + ex;
            return EmptyList;
        }

        return oResults;
    }
```

If there are any questions, please feel free to ask

Comment: You should try linq to MySQL. There are number of open source API. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend against doing this.

First off, you should only keep a connection open as long as it takes to execute the command.  Also, MySqlCommand implements IDisposable, so that should be wrapped in a using clause.

One reason I recommend against it is that this functionality is already covered.  A simple way is to have your methods just return a DataTable.  DataTables are going to give you every bit of information you'll need anyway (data type, rows, columns, etc) while yours is very limiting.

Another reason has to do with maintaining an open connection: bad idea.  Connection Pooling will take care of opening/closing connections very very quickly so it's just not necessary.  Also, in case your app crashes then you are going to be leaking connections.  At some point you'll end up with wonderful little database errors.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Before I post my new version, I was hoping if you could tell me how exactly I'm maintaining an open connection at this moment?

Comment: @Nick:Looking at your posted code, you assigned a property named Connection to your command object.  So, it's obvious that it is created elsewhere.  Also, your command object never closes.  Between the two its apparent that once the query is done the command object is left hanging and the outer Connection property isn't dealt with.  Both your command and connection objects implement IDisposable.  Which means they should be wrapped in using clauses.. within the method they are actually used.

Answer (score 2):

A .NET DataTable is a collection of DataRows, and each DataRow has an Object array ItemArray

```
DataTable GetTable()
  {
    try
    {
        string query = "select * from items";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(DS);
        return DS.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 good example.  I'm not crazy about DataAdapters but they are certainly preferable to what the OP has.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't want to use a DataAdapter because I'm not too fond of them either. But I've decided to go with it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As you get a DataSet you can get easily access to the rows of any specified table, using DataRowCollection:

```
DataRowCollection drc = dataSet.Tables["tableName"].Rows;
```

instead of tableName we can write also table index but it is not reccomended, when we add or remove tables from database indexes will change. Names will be still same after those operations.